# How to use filter legend by map content for more maps

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend, filter

I have QGIS 2.10.1. I have 31 maps in print composer. Each maps is vector layer which involves a lot of polygons with ID. The problem is when I want to use legend and need to show only polygons ID which I can see in print composer. I try to use filter legend by map content, but it shows only 1 map. I don't know how to use this "filter legend by map content" to other maps in print composer.

How can the legend show all polygons in all 31 maps?

[image]

The legend show all polygons of each layers. But the problem is that not right. I add a my personal colour style for polygons and it shows all id and colours which are define in this style. Not only existing in this layer. I try to do it by my hand but the colour doesnt fit. Maybr the problem is because this style. Do you know how to fix it? Or how to change setting in style? I set categorized and then add style...

Comment: What if you add a map item who's extent covers all 31 maps (move it off the print page) and use that for the legend?

Comment: Sorry, the problem is still not clear to me. This should be doable with one map and maybe the filter legend function if the style contains too many classes that are not actually used on any map.

Comment: Ok, than you for your try to help. I appreciate it